# Why oracle sql not allow sysdate in table creation time for count age?

Tags: oracle

Query....
I want to try to make check constraints on birthdate and check age should be greater than 18.

```
Create table emp
(
Birthdate date,
Check( MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,Birthdate))
);
```

Error on above query....why?
Anyone help me...

Why oracle sql not allow sysdate in table creation time for count age?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205) says you can't call non-deterministic functions.

Answer (score 2):

SYSDATE is not allowed because the constraint must be either "true" or "false" at any time you look at the data. If you were able to use SYSDATE in a check constraint, you could insert a row that satisfied the constraint at that time, but the constraint would be violated later. No good!

In your example, once the constraint is satisfied at insert time, it can't become "not satisfied" later. But here you are asking Oracle to think. It can't. It just doesn't allow you to use SYSDATE in constraints. Period.

Instead, you should write a simple trigger to do the check for you. Note that you are missing the comparison to 18 * 12 in your purported check constraint; MONTHS_BETWEEN may give some weird results in some cases; and it is always best to write code that mirrors your thinking: in this case the condition (in a trigger, not a check constraint) should be ***

```
sysdate >= birthdate + interval '18' year
```

***   ***EDIT***: As Alex Poole points out below, adding INTERVAL to a date may sometimes be as weird as MONTHS_BETWEEN. The safe way to write the check is

```
sysdate >= add_months ( birthdate, 18 * 12 )   --  age >= 18 years or 18 * 12 months
```

(That is how I would write it - with the comment to explain the purpose, and 18 * 12.)

Comment: Adding an interval to a date will fail in some cases; in this scenario, for a birthdate on February 29th. (e.g. `date '2000-02-29 + interval '18' year` will get "ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified".) Using `add_months()` and 18*12 is safer here.

Comment: @AlexPoole - ugh, I knew that about MONTHS_BETWEEN; it never occurred to me to check it for INTERVAL. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
SQL> create table person
(name varchar2(100),
dob date,
created_date date default sysdate not null,
constraint dob_check check
     (
        dob <= add_months(trunc(created_date), (12*18)*-1)
     )
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into person(name,dob) values ('Bob', to_date('19740101','YYYYMMDD'))
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> insert into person(name,dob) values ('Jane', to_date('20050101','YYYYMMDD'))
insert into person(name,dob) values ('Jane', to_date('20050101','YYYYMMDD'))
Error at line 17
ORA-02290: check constraint (MYUSER.DOB_CHECK) violated
```

Comment: @GautamMistry - please see ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the help center. If this is the approach you used then consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Oracle limitation. The reason is SYSDATE is non-deterministic. You can get a different result every time you call it. So the outcome (true/false) can (will) change over time. So Oracle can't guarantee that the expression is always true for every row.

See also https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=sysdate-in-check-constraints

Comment: I wouldn't call that an "Oracle limitation". An Oracle limitation is the lack of BOOLEAN data type. The restriction on SYSDATE is a logical restriction, it has nothing to do with Oracle being somehow limited. (As you do, in fact, explain in your answer!)